# How to change elements of interface in Grafna only for viewer version of page (by changing source code)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, grafana

I'm trying to modifying source code of Grafana, to remove this button only for viewer version of page(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrZQE.png). Thats just example. I'm trying to understand how to change elements of interface only for viewer version of page. I'm running Grafana with WSL Ubuntu version 22.04.

I found code responding for this button, it located in /grafana/public/app/core/components/AppChrome/NavToolbar/NavToolbar.tsx.

```
<div className={styles.menuButton}>
        <IconButton
          name="bars"
          tooltip={t('navigation.toolbar.toggle-menu', 'Toggle menu')}
          tooltipPlacement="bottom"
          size="xl"
          onClick={onToggleMegaMenu}
        />
      </div>
```

Editing this code effects all pages not only for user.

I'm new in FrontEnd and grafana, can someone, please, explain me how to change elements of interface only for viewer.

Comment: Deleting downvoted and/or closed question and immediately re-asking the same question is not a viable strategy to get help, but it's very good strategy to get a [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583).

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem in my question. I edited it and it remained closed

Comment: Your edit didn't make your question better. You need to focus on one **specific question**. Right now it's extremely broad and cannot be answered in reasonable manner.

Comment: If you don't know where to find toolbar for modification you need to investigate which framework is used (maybe react? I'm not sure), provide all related information about what you already know: link to repo, your understanding of repo structure and so on (not really familiar with frontend questions, but in general more is better). And apply all related tags (single grafana tag wouldn't do much good.

Comment: Additionally, SO is not a free helpdesk for all kind of questions. It is expected that before asking question here, you've done your fair share of research. And that your question will be useful for other users in future.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll to find needed information and specify question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.